# DataGridView: Which Event do I need?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the DGV bound to data and all the other controls properly. What I am trying to do now is update a PictureBox based on the contents of the data row. The picture is not a part of the bound data, its always available on the web. I have a function that will build the url string to a webserver with the images I need.

The problem is that I can figure out the proper event. Mouse Click works perfectly but doesnt allow for keyboard selection (ie bound fields update but pictureBox does not). RowEnter/RowLeave both leave me with the picture from the row that was previously selected, never the current row.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another wild guess: SelectionChanged

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Realized you wanted it to happen when you selected a row..

```
MyGrid.RowEnter += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(MyGrid_RowEnter );

void MyGrid_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventHandlere)
{
    if (0 > e.RowIndex) return;

    //TODO: Do whatever with your image here..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wild Guess: OnRowDataBound

If you want access to a row (and its columns) as its being bound to the grid, use the event above.

You question states that your problem is that you **do** know the event, or do you mean you **dont** know the event ?

EDIT: If you want this behavior to occur client side(i.e. when selecting a row theres no postback), then some javascript like an onclick event handler on the entire row,(tr) or place a checkbox in the first column and use an onlick for that.

Otherwise you if you want a postback everytime you select a row, then you can use an event such as OnSelectedIndexChanged or the build in commands that come with the DGV.

Comment: Won't work. He wants the picture to be updated when the row is selected, not data bound.